# Kubernetes Google OAuth2 Sign In

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to figure this out for a while and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Maybe someone here will have an idea.

I have deployed an application on Kubernetes Cluster (in GCP). The Application is pretty much a micro-service type of app under a single domain. What I'm trying to achieve at the moment is to have a domain-wide-authentication via Google and OAuth2 protocol.
So I have a main app under the main domain `https://example.com` and pretty much every single path under that domain will be a separate K8s Service + Deployment. So it's a different set of containers for `https://example.com/foo` and different for `https://example.com/bar` and obviously different set of containers for the main `https://example.com`. I don't want to "connect" each individual App to Google due to two reasons:

1. Would require for me that each app has the OAuth2 Protocol implemented, and
2. A token granted by one app would be invalid for the other one, so it would require the user to log in each time he/she changes the URL, kind bad UX if you ask me

So, I'm trying to set up in the Kubernetes Cluster an Nginx Ingress Controller that would facilitate authentication and validate all incoming requests before they would reach any of the backend apps. This is where the problem lies...

I've managed to set up [OAuth2 Proxy](https://github.com/pusher/oauth2_proxy/) in my Nginx Ingress Controller and the user can log in. The whole OAuth2 Flow works. HOWEVER, the user is not forced to log in. The user can navigate to the `https://example.com` but he/she won't be required to have an Authentication cookie granted after successful login via Google.

Here is my YAML config for Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: example-com-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-com-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: oauth2-proxy
            servicePort: http-proxy
          path: /oauth2
        - backend:
            serviceName: example-com-nginx-service
            servicePort: 80
          path: /
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that while configuring oauth2 proxy you set your cookie domain  (set   `--cookie-domain=example.com`  to allow the cookie to be read).

You have to also add  the `whitelist-domain` feature while configuring oauth2 proxy:

```
--whitelist-domain=example.com
```

Then have to create ingress' obects:

**1.** Expose endpoint `/oauth2`, look at the example below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180
        path: /oauth2
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: example-com-tls
```

**2.**  Then create ingress for your application:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-com-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
    secretName: example-com-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: example-com-nginx-service
          servicePort: 80
```

It is clearly to create two separate ingresses, but you can also create just one with two defined backends as you wanted.

Take a look here: [nginx-ingress-controller-oauth2](https://toolbox.kurio.co.id/securing-your-website-with-oauth2-in-nginx-ingress-controller-c84984eae7fa), [oauth2-dynamic-callbacks](https://elsesiy.com/blog/oauth2-proxy-dynamic-callback-urls), [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/109).

Once again make sure that you have follow this instruction: [external-OAUTH-authentication](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/).

Comment: Ok, I've tried to do it, but didn't work. I'm failing to understand in that solution how the two Ingresses are connected. If one exposes the service under the main domain and the other the `/oauth2` path, why the two are required?

Having one Ingress I can have different services under different paths and under the same domain. Why the two and still how they are connected?

My oauth2 proxy is available, just not forcing the auth flow.

Nonetheless, will try again, maybe the first time I've configured it wrong

Comment: The second time I've tried it the results were the same. My "main" `Ingress` (with the nginx) doesn't forward traffic to the `Ingress` with oauth2, which results in `404` from the nginx. These results make sense to me, because the public DNS servers are aware of only one IP address which points to the "main" `Ingress`. If that LoadBalancer doesn't forward traffic to different services and/or HTTP servers than the "main one" will respond, which it does and I get a `404`. :(

Comment: Did you create also service for both of them ?

Comment: both of the deployments - nginx and oauth2 - yes I did. Unless there are some other services needed...

Comment: Yes, I meant services for these specific deployments. Can you double check if you passed proper arguments to running oauth2-proxy container (client id, client secret, provider etc)?  Finally if it won't work change annotation in your default Ingress conf file from ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true" to ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true", in your version - because you are not using default built in gce but nginx. And try to run just only this one ingress.

Comment: Yes, the secret and client id is passed (stored in a `kubernetes secret` and passed as `env` variables to the OAuth2 proxy pods). Provider is the default one  - `google` so all good on that. I know those things work because with the "single" ingress setup if I navigate to `/oauth2` path I'll get a `Sign in via Google` button and I can go through the flow and at the end I'll get the Session Cookie stored in my browser under my domain. This only works if I (the user) will go to that path, but I won't be forced on that path if I don't have the cookie.

Comment: Not sure what you want me to change, those `annotations` seem the same to me :/

Comment: I guess the goal would be to force the user to be redirected to `https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri` this forces the OAuth2 flow and after a successful login the user will be navigated back to the URL he/she started from

Comment: Please continue on a chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209985/oauth2. I made mistake, please change annotation: from ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true" to nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true".

Comment: Take a look above, I have edited my answer. Does it clarify your doubts ? Did you manage to configure it once again ?